# Express.js session with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, session, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a light weight application with Express.js. I would like to use Sqlite3 for storage.

I need some sort of session management and trying to use the session management module described in the Express guide document like so (CoffeeScript)

```
g.app.configure -> 
  g.app.set 'views', "#{__dirname}/views"
  g.app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
  g.app.use g.express.bodyParser()
  g.app.use g.express.cookieParser()
  g.app.use g.express.session(secret:'cruel')
  g.app.use g.express.methodOverride()
  g.app.use g.app.router
  g.app.use g.express.static "#{__dirname}/public"
```

Now I would like to store the sessions either in sqlite3 or as files in the project path somehow.

All examples I find use different kinds of NoSql-databases.

Could anyone shed some light on where to find other session store modules, or even how to implement one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these 3 links will be useful for you:

http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html (at the bottom of the page)

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session/memory.js

(the default memory store for session that connect has built-in)

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki (Session Stores)

From the Connect guide (Connect Session page):

**Session Store Implementation**

Every session store must implement the following methods

```
* .get(sid, callback)
* .set(sid, session, callback)
* .destroy(sid, callback)
```

Recommended methods include, but are not limited to:

```
* .length(callback)
* .clear(callback)
```

For an example implementation view the connect-redis repo.

```
* param Object options
* returns Function
```

Comment: Some of these links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

> All examples I find use different
>   kinds of NoSql-databases.

The nice thing about a lot of those NoSQL databases is that they are really easy to install. Installing redis is very easy and will make your site a lot faster(in memory database backupped by disc)...

> Could anyone shed some light on where
>   to find other session store modules

I found the following modules using http://search.npmjs.org / http://github.com searches:

- https://github.com/pkrumins/supermarket-cart

  > Supermarket-cart can be used to store
  >   connect's sessions in supermarket
  >   database.

  **I believe this uses sqlite.**
- http://search.npmjs.org/#/connect-cookie-session:

  > A Connect middleware to allow you to
  >   store your sessions directly in the
  >   client's cookie.
- https://github.com/caolan/cookie-sessions

  > Secure cookie-based session middleware
  >   for Connect.
- https://github.com/creationix/nstore-session

  > This is a simple session store for
  >   Connect that uses nStore for
  >   persisting session data.
- https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

  > connect-redis is a Redis session store
  >   backed by node_redis, and is insanely
  >   fast :)
- https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb
- https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo

This is what I found quickly, but when doing a more thoroughly search I believe you should be able to find even more session implementations.

> or even how to implement one.

I think you should be able to use supermarket-cart, but you could also implement your own store by using this links as a reference:

- http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html
- https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I started to write my own sessionstore. But it doesnt work very well just yet.

Comment: NPM search link is dead, FYI.